# How to filter the matched element at top index in an array in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I have a list of array as follows:

```
 var arr = ['Ashwin Rathod','Basker Babu','Cherry Spanish','Dravid Mukund'];
```

I have a search box and If I search for 'Mukund',then I should show all the results provided the string which contains 'Mukund' should come at top but in my case all the results are coming in alphabetical order(from backend).I did that using array.filter but I want to do it in any other best way.Can anyone please suggest me help.Thanks.

This is what I tried,

```js
function filterResults() {
  const matchedJobList = [],
        unMatchedJobList = [];

  arr.filter(function(job) {
    if (job.toUpperCase().includes(mySearchedString.toUpperCase())) {
      matchedJobList.push(job);
    } else {
      unmatchedJobList.push(job);
    }
  });

  return [...matchedJobList, ...unmatchedJobList];
}
```

result:

```
['Dravid Mukund','Ashwin Rathod','Basker Babu','Cherry Spanish'];
```

I got the result as expected but hoping to get the best method to do it.

Comment: This looks fine as it is. You could replace the `filter` with `forEach` as it isn't returning anything.

Comment: Just as a side note, you're not using `.filter()` correctly. The callback should `return` true or false depending on whether you want to keep the given element in the array. The new filtered array is then returned by `.filter()` (which you're not doing anything with). See docs on [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: `filter` was perfect if you wanted to return ONLY matching results

Comment: That is not filtering, that is sorting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative could be the function `reduce` + `unshift` in order to add the target strings at the first indexes of the array.

```js
let arr = ['Ashwin Rathod','Basker Babu','Cherry Spanish','Dravid Mukund'],
    target = 'Mukund',
    result = arr.reduce((a, c) => {
      if (c.toUpperCase().includes(target.toUpperCase())) a.unshift(c);
      else a.push(c);
      return a;
    }, []);
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks @Ele, this suits me perfectly but a question,according to reduce definition,it should only result a single value but here we are returning an array.Is that having a conflict with the definition? Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @user11917666 a single value (aka accumulator) could be anything in js, in this case, an Array.  The most important thing is always to think about what you want to generate (single value/accumulator) as a result.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind the potential change of unmatched items order then you can go for sort function:

```
function filterResults() {
    const sorderArray = [...arr];
    sorderArray.sort(item => item.toUpperCase().indexOf(mySearchedString.toUpperCase()) !== -1 ? -1 : 1);

    return sorderArray;
}
```

Sort function works directly on the array so I'm creating a copy of the `arr` to prevent it's mutation.

Answer (score 0):

That is not filtering, that is sorting.

```js
const arr = ['Ashwin Rathod', 'Basker Babu', 'Cherry Spanish', 'Dravid Mukund'];
const mySearchedString = 'Mukund';

function filterResults() {
  const clonedResults = [...arr];
  return clonedResults.sort((job1, job2) => {
    const job1match = job1.toUpperCase().includes(mySearchedString.toUpperCase());
    const job2match = job2.toUpperCase().includes(mySearchedString.toUpperCase());
    if (job2match && !job1match) return 1;
    return 0;
  });
}


console.log(filterResults());
```

Answer (score 0):

We can move founded element to the top:

```js
let arr = ['Ashwin Rathod','Basker Babu','Cherry Spanish','Dravid Mukund'],
search = 'Mukund';


arr.forEach((element, ind) => {
  if (element.indexOf(search))
    arr.unshift(arr.splice(ind, 1)[0]);
});
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [`splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

```js
const arr = ['Ashwin Rathod', 'Basker Babu', 'Cherry Spanish', 'Dravid Mukund']
const search = 'Mukund'

const index = arr.findIndex(e => e.includes(search))

console.log([...arr.splice(index, 1), ...arr]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using a sort for this, not a filter. Here is an example using a sort method.

```js
const getMatchingLetters = (word, search) => {
    return word.toLowerCase().split("").filter(l => {
        return search.toLowerCase().includes(l);
    })
}

const sortBySearch = (arr, search) => {
    return arr.sort((a, b) => {
        return getMatchingLetters(a, search).length - getMatchingLetters(b, search).length
    }).reverse();
}

const myArray = ['Ashwin Rathod','Basker Babu','Cherry Spanish','Dravid Mukund'];
const searchTerm = "Mukund";
console.log(sortBySearch(myArray, searchTerm));
```